# How to Drag, Drop and Resize Label on a Panel at runtime? C#, winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, label, panel

I have this code for dragging on a Panel but its not doing the thing.
I have to choose if I will just Drag&drop or Resize. 
I think theres something wrong with my code here in form load.
Anyway I have 5 labels here and a panel named as label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 on panel1.

```
    private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //for drag and drop           
            //this.panel1.AllowDrop = true; // or Allow drop in the panel.
            foreach (Control c in this.panel1.Controls)
            {
                c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(c_MouseDown);
            }
            this.panel1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragOver);
            this.panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);  

            //end of drag and drop
    }

    void c_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = sender as Control;                       
            c.DoDragDrop(c, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;
        lblResizeAmtWord.Visible = false;
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            //this.panel1.Controls.Add(c); //disable if already on the panel
        }
    }

    void panel1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```

Comment: D+D **always** requires implementing the DragEnter event.  Only use DragOver if the drop should be selective for certain parts of the control.  Using the events for the panel but not the controls on the panel makes it difficult for the user to pick a drop target.

Comment: So what do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Anyway I solved it myself. For those who want to know its just so easy. :D

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer if you resolved it.

Comment: I think asking is better so that I will know that the person is really interested.

Comment: @ViFer could you please post your answer - i am trying to do this as well and havent a clue :/

Comment: @JazziJeff Ok i will post the answer.

Comment: @JazziJeff you got it?

Comment: @JazziJeff Your welcome! Already up-voted it for others to see also?

Comment: @JazziJeff Alright! Your welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the MouseDown, Up and Move Event of the Control I want to move. Let's say my control name is ctrlToMove.

```
    private Point _Offset = Point.Empty;
    private void ctrlToMove_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _Offset = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }

    private void ctrlToMove_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _Offset = Point.Empty;
    }

    private void ctrlToMove_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_Offset != Point.Empty)
        {
            Point newlocation = ctrlToMove.Location;
            newlocation.X += e.X - _Offset.X;
            newlocation.Y += e.Y - _Offset.Y;
            ctrlToMove.Location = newlocation;
        }
    }
```